# Orthogonal vectors such that $X^T S X + Y^T S Y = 0$ (in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Say I have a 3x3 symmetric matrix $S$, having two positive and one negative eigenvalue.

I'm looking for two orthogonal **unit** vectors $X$ and $Y$ such that

$$X^T S X + Y^T S Y = 0$$

I have tried to solve it using spherical or cartesian parametrizations of $X$ and $Y$ but it quickly becomes painful. Do you know a way to solve this ?

Edit : I should insist on the **unit vector requirement**, otherwise the problem is indeed easier.

Comment: Could you say some words about the context in which you have met this issue ?

Comment: @JeanMarie This identity appears in the derivative of some cost function I want to minimize, as a factor I don't want to be zero. By trying to find when such a quantity is zero, I want to make sure my optimization results still hold.

In my problem, matrix $S$ is $S = P^{-2}P_kP^{-1}+P^{-1}P_kP^{-2}$, where $P = \sum_{k=0}^{N}w_kP_k$ and $P_k = I - u_k^{T}u_k$, $u_k$ being a unit vector.

Comment: @ Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the three eigenvalues $a,b$ and $-c$, where $a\ge b\ge0\ge-c$. Complete $\{x,y\}$ to an orthonormal basis $\{x,y,z\}$ and let $Q$ be the augmented matrix $[x,y,z]$. Then $Q$ is orthogonal and
$$
a+b-c=\operatorname{tr}(S)=\operatorname{tr}(Q^TSQ)=x^TSx+y^TSy+z^TSz=z^TSz.
$$
Since $-c\le z^TSz\le a$, we see that a solution $\{x,y\}$ exists if and only if $-c\le a+b-c\le a$, i.e. iff $c\ge b$.

In case $c\ge b$ is indeed true, take any unit vector $z$ such that $z^TSz=a+b-c$ and any two unit vectors $x,y$ that form an orthonormal basis with $z$ would give a solution to your problem. **Edit:** for instance, let $u,v,w$ be three orthonormal eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $a,b,-c$ respectively. Then $z=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a+c}}\,u+\sqrt{\frac{c-b}{a+c}}\,w$ will satisfy the equation $z^TSz=a+b-c$. Now you may take $x=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a+c}}\,w-\sqrt{\frac{c-b}{a+c}}\,u$ and $y=v$.

Comment: [+1] A very very nice answer! To readers that would ask themselves why $-c\le z^TSz\le a$, one can give the reference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

Comment: Thank you, that is smart ! I think it should help me :)

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @user1551 What about equation $z^TSz = a+b-c$ ? Is it possible to solve it for $z$ (being 1-normed), or do we have to use numerical methods ?

Comment: @user1551 yeah I had that bit and could not find any better way. I guess that is not possible to go any further to express $z$. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @user1551 in your last edit, I don't think $z$ has norm $1$.

Comment: @user1551 My apologies, that was stupid of me, I squared twice the fractions... It indeed works, thank you very much for this excellent solution !

Answer (score 2):

Here is another track, not along the same way as @user1551, that can be considered as complementary to his.

Firstly, we (very slightly!) modify the issue by replacing **unit** vectors by vectors with $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ norm.

I keep notations $a \geq b \geq 0 \geq -c$ for the eigenvalues of $S$.

Let us define $Q(X,Y):=\begin{pmatrix}X^T&Y^T\end{pmatrix}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}S&I_3\\I_3&S\end{pmatrix}}_{\Sigma}\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{X^TSX+Y^TSY}_{=0}+2X^TI_3Y=2X^TY$

that ultimately should be $0$ itself.

The eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are the eigenvalues of $S$ to which $\pm1$ is added, i.e., are

$$\tag{1}\{a+1,a-1,b+1,b-1,-c+1,-c-1\}$$

(not necessarily in that order). See proof of (1) at the end of this answer.

Thus, the extreme eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are $a+1$ and $-c-1$.

Let $U=\binom{X}{Y}$. It is clear that $\|U\|^2=\|X\|^2+\|Y\|^2 \in \mathbb{R}^6.$

The Rayleigh quotient associated with $\Sigma$ is (for $U$ such that  $\|U\|=1$) nothing else than $Q(U)$ ; it is well known that it takes every value between extreme eigenvalues $a+1$ and $-c-1$, i.e., for every $t, 0 \leq t \leq 1$, there exist $U$ such that :

$Q(U)=X^TY=t(-c-1)+(1-t)(a+1)$

In particular, the LHS is zero for the following positive value of $t$:

$$\tag{3}t=\dfrac{a+1}{a+c+2}$$

which is less than $1$, because $c \geq 0$.  BUT such orthogonal $X$ and $Y$ have no reason to be such that $\|X\|=\|Y\|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}};$

(One can have for example $U^T=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$ meaning $X^T=(1,0,0)$ and $Y^T=(0,0,0)$.)

The interest of formula (3) is when condition $c\geq b$ established by user1551 is not fulfilled. In this case, (3) provides a start for finding two vectors $X,Y$ that, can be at the same time not far from being orthogonal and not far to have a common norm $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

---

**Proof of (1):** (1) can be established

- either directly by expressing

$\tag{2}\Sigma=I_2\otimes S+\binom{0 \ 1}{1 \ 0}\otimes I_3$

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

(2) is called a ''Kronecker sum'' (notation $M \oplus N=I_n\otimes M+N\otimes I_p$); a classical theorem says that the eigenvalues of $M \oplus N$ are obtained by summing, in all possible ways, an eigenvalue of $M$ with an eigenvalue of $N$.

- or in a computational way by applying  Schur's complement identity:

$$det\begin{pmatrix}A&C\\B&D\end{pmatrix}=det(D)det(D-BA^{-1}C)$$

to a diagonalized form of $\Sigma-\lambda I_6$.

Comment: The catch is that when the Rayleigh quotient vanishes at some vector $(x^T,y^T)^T$, we may not have $\|x\|=\|y\|$.

Comment: @user1551 But I have assumed that I work only with norm 1 vectors. Nevertheless, it must be along such a limitation that the problem is.

Comment: I have added a more direct explanation for the eigenvalues of $B$ using Kronecker's sum.

Comment: @user1551 Now I realize: you are right. Here is the problem. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @user1551 I have posted the new version.

Comment: I understand your thinking till equation 3. But do we then have a way to explicitly build $X$ and $Y$ ? What about their norms ?

Comment: We have proven that the set of points $U=(u,v,w,x,y,z)$ is nonvoid; this set is representable as a second degree hypersurface in $\mathbb{R^6}$ ; we have to find points $(u,v,w,x,y,z)$ on this surface that belong (in the good cases) or are the closest possible to hypersurface with equation $u^2+v^2+w^3=x^2+y^2+z^2$ expressing the equality of norms. There are numerical methods for that.